# How to sum a cell and the surround cells within a matrix

Tags: java

I want to sum cells. I mean, surrounding cells. Add the cell I call upon and add that value with values around it. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class MatrixSummingRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] mat = { { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 8, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1 },
                { 0, 2, 7, 8, 9, 8, 0 }, { 0, 6, 7, 6, 2, 5, 0 },
                { 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 0 }, { 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 } };
        out.println("Sum of the given values, at {4,2} and the values around it"
                + MatrixSumming(mat, 4, 2));
        out.println("Sum of the given values, at {3,3} and the values around it"
                + MatrixSumming(mat, 3, 3));
        out.println("Sum of the given values, at {5,4} and the values around it"
                + MatrixSumming(mat, 5, 4));
        out.println(toString(mat));
    }
}
```

That's the runner, and now what I THOUGHT WOULD WORK.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatrixSumming {
    private int[][] m = { { 4, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 5, 4 } }; // load in the matrix
                                                          // values

    public int sum(int[][] mat, int x, int y) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int item : mat) {
            Sum = getValueAt(x, y) + getValueAt(x++, y) + getValueAt(x--, y)
                    + getValueAt(x--, y++) + getValueAt(x--, y--)
                    + getValueAt(x++, y++) + getValueAt(x++, y--);
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Apparently that didn't work. It's counting them as individual variables, causing a massive problem for me...

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make any sense:

```
   for(int item : mat)
    {
        Sum=getValueAt(x,y) + getValueAt(x++,y) + getValueAt(x--,y) + getValueAt(x--,y++) + getValueAt(x--,y--) + getValueAt(x++,y++) + getValueAt(x++,y--);
    }
```

For starters, you're modifying the x and y variables inside of this function. Instead, just use +1 and -1 where appropriate.

Secondly, you've never defined a Sum variable, and you're overwriting the value every time the loop increments. Instead, you need to add the values to the existing sum from previous times the loop has fired.

Here's an example of how you might figure out the sum from an array:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int x : array){
   sum = sum+x;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing a method and a reference to the runner as well